# getUser() returns null, session is not started in my symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony, session

On the latest Symfony 2 version (using FOSUserBundle and SonataUserBundle), I am trying to get the current user in order to pre-fill a form in my new Entity controller.

On **mycontroller.yml**:

```
my_controller_new:
    pattern:  /new
    defaults: { _controller: "MySiteBundle:MyController:new" }
```

On **MyController.php** :

```
public function newAction()
{
  $user = $this->getUser();
  // ...
}
```

But when I call `$this->getUser()`, the method returns `null`. Even though I am logged in (I can access `/profile` and update my user info without any problem)

I then tried to check is the session was started:

```
public function newAction()
{
  var_dump($this->get('session')->isStarted());
  // ...
}
```

It returns false. What is wrong here?

Comment: $this->get('session')->isStarted() return false means your session not started.

Comment: Yes, I mention it in the title, but I am wondering why.

Comment: ,I have posted answer please check it if it helps to resolve your issue !

Comment: Is that controller behind a firewall?

Comment: Indeed it was... I had named the route "images", which was conflicting with another one. Nothing to see here folks, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function newAction() { 

        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession(); // Get started session
        if(!$session instanceof Session)
            $session = new Session(); // if there is no session, start it

        $value = $session->getId(); // get session id
    }
```

Comment: No errors with that code, but getId() returns an empty string.

Comment: @BraveKenny,Where do you save your user session ? I think it might not be store user data in to session that's why you're not get the user session data.